If you wanted to refer to "colorism" in Japanese, would "肌色差別" be the correct term?
I couldn't find the term for "colorism" in Japanese, discrimination based on the tone of someone's skin. Would 肌色差別 be an appropriate term or is there another word for it?

I didn't even know that was an English word until now: https://globalsocialtheory.org/topics/colourism/

肌色差別 sounds puzzling because the word 肌色 normally refers to this specific color that represents the average skin color of the majority of Japanese people (i.e., light orange). 肌の色による差別 would make sense as a description, but if you're referring to a certain established academic concept, it's usually best to just katakanize "colorism".

Colorism is not a concept that will be familiar or relevant to most Japanese. Google Scholar finds a grand total of 2 hits for 肌色差別, so the word exists, but only barely.
These days, if an English word doesn't exist in Japanese, it's more common to import it as katakana instead of trying to come up with new kanji compounds. Indeed, existing literature on the subject seems to use カラリズム (4 cites on Scholar) or カラーリズム (2), which is not a lot, but still 3x more.
